# Finite covering of bounded, open sets

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Consider $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded. Let $c>0$ be given. Is it possible fo find $V_1,...,V_n\subset \Omega$ with $|V_i|\leq c$ for all $i$, $|V_i\cap V_j|=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $ \Omega \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$.

I think this can be done by taking $(V_i)_{i=1}^n$ to be a rhombuses. Nevertheless I don't have any reference. I would be thankful for any reference or any other idea.

Comment: Yes, because $\Omega $ is [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space).

Comment: The number of these $V_j$ is the same as the dimension? Then no. Choose for example $c:=\frac{|\Omega|}{2n}$ and assume you can find these $V_j$. Then $|\Omega|\leq\sum_{j=1}^n |V_j|\leq \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{|\Omega|}{2n}=\frac{|\Omega|}{2}$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of totally bounded does not require that $V_i\subset \Omega$. Can I assume this ?

Sorry, I did'nt want to take the same $n$. Assume there are finitely many $V_1,...,V_N$. Furthermore I am also only interested in a special chosen and fixed $c$.

Answer (score 0):

I recognized that by the above subset inclusion I'm asking for $(V_i)_{i=1}^N\subset \Omega$, $|V_i\cap V_j|=0$, $|V_i|\leq c$ for a fixed number $c$ so that $\Omega=\bigcup_{i=1}^N V_i$.